# MSMQ: dead-letter messages and transactional dead-letter messages

Tags: msmq, dead-letter

MSMQ system queues include a) journal messages, b) dead-letter messages, c) transactional dead-letter messages.
In "Journal messages" there are all journal messages of private queues.

I have few questions about the other two queues.
What do dead-letter messages and transactinal dead-letter messages include? Are they different compared to the messages in the private queues or are the same? If they are not the same, what kind of messages can I find here?

I had a problem with "Insufficient resources to perform operation" and I was forced to purge the queues.

Answer (score 0):

They are messages that could not be delivered for whatever reason. If there are messages in these queues then they should be processed like a normal message. That is, either manually through the MMC snap-in or programmatically read to determine if further action is required. The system queues should be monitored, just like every public or private queue, to ensure they don't fill up.

Someone had to initially decide to code your application to set the journaling level (PROPID_M_JOURNAL or MSMQMessage.Journal) of the messages to MQMSG_DEADLETTER. If there is no associated process for handling the resulting deadletter messages then your server will always eventually stop working.